# Get return List on 3 tiers

Tags: c#, ado.net

I need return List on textbox and others controls... In my Gridview the result is ok. 
I use grv.Datasouce = method... Its ok. But i dont return single values.

```
    public Configuracoes() 
    {

    }

    public int conId { get; set; }
    public string conDescricao { get; set; }

}
```

}

```
    public List<Configuracoes> GetConfiguracoes()
    {

        List<Configuracoes> list = new List<Configuracoes>();

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(strAppDir))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM CAP_CONFIGURACAO ORDER BY conId", conn);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Configuracoes configuracoes = new Configuracoes();
                configuracoes.conDescricao = reader["conDescricao"].ToString();
                list.Add(configuracoes);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

how to return this for a text box ?

txt.Text = ?

Answer (score 0):

your function returns an object of type `List<Configuracoes>`, now you want to set it to a textbox Text property wich is a string, there is not way in this world that can be possible.

what you can do is make a string of your array and set it in the Text property of your textbox. something like

```
var myConfigs = GetConfiguracoes();
string myString;

foreach(var config in myConfigs){
    myString += config.conDescricao;
}

txt.Text = myString;
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Got It !

I used DataBinding on my textbox

```
txtPastaProcessada.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ds, "columnoftable", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```